# iOS Twitter API returns no followers

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-follow

I've written this code to get a list of follower's ids :

```
+ (void)getTwitterFriendsIDListForAccount:(ACAccount *)account withHandler:(TWFriendsListHandler)handler
{
    NSMutableString *paramString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json"];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"screen_name" : account.username};

    SLRequest *twRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                              requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                        URL:url
                                                 parameters:params];
    [twRequest setAccount:account];
    [twRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            handler(nil, error);
        }

        NSError *jsonError = nil;
        NSDictionary *twitterFriends = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                                         error:&jsonError];
        NSArray *IDlist = [twitterFriends objectForKey:@"ids"];
        int count = IDlist.count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            [paramString appendFormat:@"%@", [IDlist objectAtIndex:i]];
            if (i < count - 1) {
                NSString *delimeter = @",";
                [paramString appendString:delimeter];
            }
        }
        [self getFollowerNameFromID:paramString forAccount:account withHandler:handler];
    }];
}
```

The account parameter is taken from ACAccountStore and is NOT null and yet I'm getting an empty response - the responseData contains 0 bytes. This used to work several weeks ago, so I don't see what the problem could be. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the url. It needs to use https instead of http protocol.